# How to detect if a script is being sourced

Tags: bash, ksh

I have a script where I do not want it to call `exit` if it's being sourced.

I thought of checking if `$0 == bash` but this has problems if the script is sourced from another script, or if the user sources it from a different shell like `ksh`.

Is there a reliable way of detecting if a script is being sourced?

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back and solved it by avoiding 'exit' in all cases; "kill -INT $$" terminates the script safely in either case.

Comment: Did you notice [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776166/2996101)? It is given 5 years later from the accepted, but it has "batteries included".

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This seems to be portable between Bash and Korn:

```
[[ $_ != $0 ]] && echo "Script is being sourced" || echo "Script is a subshell"
```

A line similar to this or an assignment like `pathname="$_"` (with a later test and action) must be on the first line of the script or on the line after the shebang (which, if used, should be for ksh in order for it to work under the most circumstances).

Comment: Unfortunately it's not guaranteed to work.  If the user has set `BASH_ENV`, `$_` at the top of the script will be the last command run from `BASH_ENV`.

Comment: This will also not work if you use bash to execute the script, e.g.

    $ bash script.sh

then the $_ would be /bin/bash instead of ./script.sh, which is the case you expect, when the script is invoked in this way:

    $ ./script.sh

In any case detecting with `$_` is a problem.

Comment: Additional tests could be included to check for those invocation methods.

Comment: Unfortunely, that's wrong! see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23009039/1765658)

Comment: @UpAndAdam: True, captured or *used* immediately. I have described the latter in my answer.

Comment: Might be good to emphasize that point given the importance of portability in this question

Comment: To summarize: While this approach _typically_ works, it is _not robust_; it fails in the following 2 scenarios: (a) `bash script` (invocation via shell executable, which this solution misreports as _sourced_), and (b) (far less likely) `echo bash; . script` (if `$_` happens to match the shell sourcing the script, this solution misreports it as a _subshell_).
Only _shell-specific_ special variables (e.g, `$BASH_SOURCE`) allow robust solutions (it follows that there is no robust POSIX-compliant solution). It _is_ possible, albeit cumbersome, to craft a robust cross-shell test.

Comment: @JPope2014: The answer is in the OP's question. "Initially I though checking if $0 == bash but this has problems if the script is sourced from another script, or if the user sources it from ksh."

Comment: fails when echo "anything" is used before this

Comment: @meso_2600: I say "must be on the first line of the script" in my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work. I tested on Ubuntu 14.04 with BASH.

Comment: Does not work for me. Should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 292):

**Robust solutions for `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`**, including a **cross-shell** one, plus a **reasonably robust POSIX-compliant solution**:

- Version numbers given are the ones on which functionality was *verified* - likely, these solutions work on much earlier versions, too - *feedback welcome*.
- Using **POSIX features only** (such as in `dash`, which acts as  `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu), there is **no *robust* way** to determine if a script is being sourced - see below for the best *approximation*.

**Important**:

- **The solutions determine whether the script is being sourced *by its caller***, which may be a shell itself *or another script* (which may or may not be sourced *itself*):

  - Also detecting the latter case adds complexity; **if you do *not* need to detect the case when your script is being sourced *by another script***, you can use the following, relatively simple POSIX-compliant solution:

    ```bash
     # Helper function
     is_sourced() {
       if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then 
           case $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT in *:file:*) return 0;; esac
       else  # Add additional POSIX-compatible shell names here, if needed.
           case ${0##*/} in dash|-dash|bash|-bash|ksh|-ksh|sh|-sh) return 0;; esac
       fi
       return 1  # NOT sourced.
     }

     # Sample call.
     is_sourced && sourced=1 || sourced=0
    ```
- **All solutions below must run in the *top-level scope* of your script**, *not inside functions*.

**One-liners** follow - explanation below; the cross-shell version is complex, but it should work robustly:

- **bash** (verified on 3.57, 4.4.19, and 5.1.16)

```bash
(return 0 2>/dev/null) && sourced=1 || sourced=0
```

- **ksh** (verified on 93u+)

```bash
[[ "$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$0")" != "$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "${.sh.file}")" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "${.sh.file}")" ]] && sourced=1 || sourced=0
```

- **zsh** (verified on 5.0.5)

```bash
[[ $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT =~ :file$ ]] && sourced=1 || sourced=0
```

- **cross-shell (bash, ksh, zsh)**

```bash
(
  [[ -n $ZSH_VERSION && $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT =~ :file$ ]] || 
  [[ -n $KSH_VERSION && "$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$0")" != "$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "${.sh.file}")" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "${.sh.file}")" ]] || 
  [[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]] && (return 0 2>/dev/null)
) && sourced=1 || sourced=0
```

- **POSIX-compliant**; not a *one-liner* (single pipeline) for technical reasons and **not *fully* robust** (see bottom):

```bash
sourced=0
if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then 
  case $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT in *:file) sourced=1;; esac
elif [ -n "$KSH_VERSION" ]; then
  [ "$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$0")" != "$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "${.sh.file}")" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "${.sh.file}")" ] && sourced=1
elif [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  (return 0 2>/dev/null) && sourced=1 
else # All other shells: examine $0 for known shell binary filenames.
     # Detects `sh` and `dash`; add additional shell filenames as needed.
  case ${0##*/} in sh|-sh|dash|-dash) sourced=1;; esac
fi
```

---

### Explanations

---

#### bash

```bash
(return 0 2>/dev/null) && sourced=1 || sourced=0
```

<sup>Note: The technique was adapted from [user5754163's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34642589/45375), as it turned out to be more robust than the original solution, `[[ $0 != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && sourced=1 || sourced=0`[1]</sup>

- Bash allows `return` statements only from functions and, in a script's top-level scope, only if the script is *sourced*.

  - If `return` is used in the top-level scope of a *non-sourced* script, an error message is emitted, and the exit code is set to `1`.
- `(return 0 2>/dev/null)` executes `return` in a *subshell* and suppresses the error message; afterwards the exit code indicates whether the script was sourced (`0`) or not (`1`), which is used with the `&&` and `||` operators to set the `sourced` variable accordingly.

  - Use of a subshell is necessary, because executing `return` in the top-level scope of a sourced script would exit the script.
  - <sup>Tip of the hat to [@Haozhun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521525/haozhun), who made the command more robust by explicitly using `0` as the `return` operand; he notes: per bash help of `return [N]`: "If N is omitted, the return status is that of the last command." As a result, the earlier version [which used just `return`, without an operand]
    produces incorrect result if the last command on the user's shell has a non-zero return value.</sup>

---

#### ksh

```bash
[[ "$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$0")" != "$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "${.sh.file}")" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "${.sh.file}")" ]] && sourced=1 || sourced=0
```

Special variable `${.sh.file}` is somewhat analogous to `$BASH_SOURCE`; note that `${.sh.file}` causes a *syntax error* in bash, zsh, and dash, so be sure to execute it *conditionally* in multi-shell scripts.

Unlike in bash, `$0` and `${.sh.file}` are NOT guaranteed to be the same - at different times either may be a relative path or mere file name, while the other may be a full one; therefore, both `$0` and `${.sh.file}` must be resolved to full paths before comparing. If the full paths differ, sourcing is implied.

---

#### zsh

```bash
[[ $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT =~ :file$) ]] && sourced=1 || sourced=0
```

`$ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT` contains information about the evaluation context: substring `file`, separated with `:`, is only present if the script is being sourced.

In a sourced script's top-level scope, `$ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT` *ends* with `:file`, and that's what this test is limited to. Inside a function, `:shfunc` is appended to `:file`; inside a command substitution, `:cmdsubst`, is appended.

---

#### Using POSIX features only

If you're willing to make certain assumptions, you can **make a *reasonable, but not fool-proof guess*** as to whether your script is being sourced, based on ***knowing the binary filenames* of the shells that may be executing your script**.
Notably, this means that this approach **doesn't detect the case when your script is being sourced by *another script***.

<sup>The section "How to handle sourced invocations" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835459/45375) discusses the edge cases that *cannot* be handled with POSIX features only in detail.</sup>

Examining the binary filename **relies on the standard behavior of `$0`, which `zsh`, for instance, does *not* exhibit.**

Thus, the safest approach is to **combine the robust, shell-specific methods above - which do *not* rely on `$0` - with a `$0`-based *fallback solution*** for all remaining shells.

In short: The following solution:

- in the shells that are covered with shell-specific tests: works robustly.
- in all other shells: works only as expected when the script is being sourced *directly* from such a shell, as opposed to from another script.

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Stéphane Desneux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6255594/st%c3%a9phane-desneux) and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38128348/45375) for the inspiration (transforming my cross-shell statement expression into a `sh`-compatible `if` statement and adding a handler for other shells).</sup>

```bash
sourced=0
if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then 
  case $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT in *:file) sourced=1;; esac
elif [ -n "$KSH_VERSION" ]; then
  [ "$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "$0")" != "$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "${.sh.file}")" && pwd -P)/$(basename -- "${.sh.file}")" ] && sourced=1
elif [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
  (return 0 2>/dev/null) && sourced=1 
else # All other shells: examine $0 for known shell binary filenames.
  # Detects `sh` and `dash`; add additional shell filenames as needed.
  case ${0##*/} in sh|-sh|dash|-dash) sourced=1;; esac
fi
```

Note that, for robustness, each shell binary filename (e.g. `sh`) is represented *twice* - once as-is and a second time, prefixed with `-`. This is to account for environments, such as macOS, where interactive shells are launched as *login* shells with a custom `$0` value that is the (path-less) shell filename prefixed with `-`.<sup>Thanks, [t7e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11879205/t7e).</sup>
(While `sh` and `dash` are perhaps unlikely to be used as *interactive* shells, others that you may need to add to the list may.)

---

<sup>[1] [user1902689](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902689/user1902689) discovered that `[[ $0 != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]]` yields a false positive when you execute a script *located in the `$PATH`* by passing its *mere filename* to the `bash` binary; e.g., `bash my-script`, because `$0` is then just `my-script`, whereas `$BASH_SOURCE` is the *full path*. While you normally wouldn't use this technique to invoke scripts in the `$PATH` - you'd just invoke them *directly* (`my-script`) - it *is* helpful when combined with `-x` for *debugging*.</sup>

Comment: `${0##*/}` and `$()` aren't portable to at least one older Bourne shell (that I still have to use, even if it is a shame that it is necessary): `echo ${0##*/}` yields `bad substitution`, and `echo $(dirname $0)` gives `syntax error: '(' unexpected`. `echo $0` gives `-sh`.

Comment: This fails your test and I did not source anything: echo $( echo $( echo 321 | echo $( return 0 2>/dev/null ) ) ); echo $?

Comment: There is a case where `bash` specific code fails under bash 5

Comment: @Thatoneguyfromthemovie, it's unclear how your example command relates to the answer, which is about _scripts_. Note that in your command you'll only ever see `echo`'s own exit code, which is `0` - it doesn't matter what exit code the command inside the command substitution (`$(...)`) sets; try `echo $(nosuchcommand); echo $?`

Comment: The Bash version doesn't play nice with `set -euo pipefail`.

Comment: @mhvelplund, I don't see a problem if I execute that statement first - can you describe the problem in detail? On a general note, the unspoken assumption - not just for this answer, but probably most Unix shell-scripting answer - is that options are at their default.

Comment: Please update zsh with
`case $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT in *:file*) sourced=1;; esac`
because the output can be `toplevel:file:shfunc` and not just `toplevel:file`

Comment: @t7e, I've updated the answer to make it clearer that all snippets require running in the script's top-level scope, not inside functions. Making them all work inside functions as well, across all shells, adds too much complexity.

Comment: Ok, I'll add my answer then, because I struggled to understand why that function did not work for me.

Comment: The bash method also works for zsh for me.

Comment: ubuntu 22 adds dashes, so I had to do something like that `case "$(printf '%s' "${0##*/}" | sed 's/-//')" in sh|dash|bash) echo "Bash is sourced";; esac`

Comment: Thanks, @t7e - please see my update at the bottom. I wasn't aware of Ubuntu, but it can happen on macOS too, for interactive shells. For simplicity and performance and since the list is likely to be small, I've simply doubled the `case` branch entries (`'sh|-sh|...`) rather than rely on a command substitution with `sed`

Comment: I guess, you need to change `return 1  # NOT sourced.` to `exit 1  # NOT sourced.` Because if it is sourced, use `return 0` but if it is not, `exit 1`. `return 1` may not stop the sequence while `exit 1` will be safe because the script was run in a new shell.

Comment: @t7e, the `is_sourced()` function isn't designed to _exit_, it is designed to _return to the caller_ and communicate the sourced status via its exit code (`0` for sourced, `1` for non-sourced); The sample statement `is_sourced && sourced=1 || sourced=0` acts on that code.

Comment: In the current code, you have a comment `return 1 # NOT sourced`, but that case where `is_sourced=1` is the case where it _is_ sourced. Remove the word `NOT` in the comment.

Comment: @HumpbackWhale194, `1` as an _exit code_ correctly indicates the _non-sourced case_, signaled via a _nonzero exit code_. That is, the exit-code logic is the _inverse_ of the logic expressed in the quasi-Boolean `sourced` variable: In other words: exit code 0` means _success_ - which triggers the `&&` operand -  and any _nonzero_ exit code means _failure_, which triggers the `||` operand in the `is_sourced && sourced=1 || sourced=0` statement.

Answer (score 228):

If your Bash version knows about the BASH_SOURCE array variable, try something like:

```
# man bash | less -p BASH_SOURCE
#[[ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -le 2 ]] && echo 'No BASH_SOURCE array variable' && exit 1

[[ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" != "${0}" ]] && echo "script ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} is being sourced ..."
```

Comment: That's maybe the cleanest way as $BASH_SOURCE is intended for that purpose exactly.

Comment: Note that this won't work under ksh which is a condition that the OP specified.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` instead of just `$BASH_SOURCE`? And `${0}` vs `$0`?

Comment: `BASH_SOURCE` is an array variable (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html)) that holds a stack trace of sources, where `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` is the latest one. The braces are used here to tell the bash what is part of the variable name. They are not necessary for `$0` in this case, but they do not hurt either. ;)

Comment: @Konrad, and if you expand `$array`, you get `${array[0]}` by default. So, again, is there a reason[...]?

Comment: Thanks for the "less -p <pattern>" usage -- very useful option which I had missed.

Comment: yeahhh, $_ vs $0 doesn't work, ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} vs $0 works!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the only reason I can think of is that `$array == ${array[0]}` is a weird and unexpected bit of idiosyncratic syntax.  A reader unfamiliar with that fact about bash variable expansion could be confused by the less-explicit syntax.

Comment: Not sure if the double "" quotes within the double [[ ]] brackets are necessary.

Answer (score 83):

After reading @DennisWilliamson's answer, there are some issues, see below:

As this question stand for [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) **and** [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), there is another part in this answer concerning [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh)... see below.

#### Simple [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) way

```
[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ]
```

Let's try (on the fly because that bash could ;-):

```
source <(echo $'#!/bin/bash
           [ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ] && v=own || v=sourced;
           echo "process $$ is $v ($0, $BASH_SOURCE)" ')
process 29301 is sourced (bash, /dev/fd/63)

bash <(echo $'#!/bin/bash
           [ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ] && v=own || v=sourced;
           echo "process $$ is $v ($0, $BASH_SOURCE)" ')
process 16229 is own (/dev/fd/63, /dev/fd/63)
```

I use `source` instead off `.` for readability (as `.` is an alias to `source`):

```
. <(echo $'#!/bin/bash
           [ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ] && v=own || v=sourced;
           echo "process $$ is $v ($0, $BASH_SOURCE)" ')
process 29301 is sourced (bash, /dev/fd/63)
```

Note that process number don't change while process stay *sourced*:

```
echo $$
29301
```

#### Why not to use `$_ == $0` comparison

For ensuring many case, I begin to write a **true** script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# As $_ could be used only once, uncomment one of two following lines

#printf '_="%s", 0="%s" and BASH_SOURCE="%s"\n' "$_" "$0" "$BASH_SOURCE"
[[ "$_" != "$0" ]] && DW_PURPOSE=sourced || DW_PURPOSE=subshell

[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ] && BASH_KIND_ENV=own || BASH_KIND_ENV=sourced;
echo "proc: $$[ppid:$PPID] is $BASH_KIND_ENV (DW purpose: $DW_PURPOSE)"
```

Copy this to a file called `testscript`:

```
cat >testscript   
chmod +x testscript
```

Now we could test:

```
./testscript 
proc: 25758[ppid:24890] is own (DW purpose: subshell)
```

That's ok.

```
. ./testscript 
proc: 24890[ppid:24885] is sourced (DW purpose: sourced)

source ./testscript 
proc: 24890[ppid:24885] is sourced (DW purpose: sourced)
```

That's ok.

But,for testing a script before adding `-x` flag:

```
bash ./testscript 
proc: 25776[ppid:24890] is own (DW purpose: sourced)
```

Or to use pre-defined variables:

```
env PATH=/tmp/bintemp:$PATH ./testscript 
proc: 25948[ppid:24890] is own (DW purpose: sourced)

env SOMETHING=PREDEFINED ./testscript 
proc: 25972[ppid:24890] is own (DW purpose: sourced)
```

This won't work anymore.

Moving comment from 5th line to 6th would give more readable answer:

```
./testscript 
_="./testscript", 0="./testscript" and BASH_SOURCE="./testscript"
proc: 26256[ppid:24890] is own

. testscript 
_="_filedir", 0="bash" and BASH_SOURCE="testscript"
proc: 24890[ppid:24885] is sourced

source testscript 
_="_filedir", 0="bash" and BASH_SOURCE="testscript"
proc: 24890[ppid:24885] is sourced

bash testscript 
_="/bin/bash", 0="testscript" and BASH_SOURCE="testscript"
proc: 26317[ppid:24890] is own

env FILE=/dev/null ./testscript 
_="/usr/bin/env", 0="./testscript" and BASH_SOURCE="./testscript"
proc: 26336[ppid:24890] is own
```

#### Harder: [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) now...

As I don't use [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) a lot, after some read on the man page, there is my tries:

```
#!/bin/ksh

set >/tmp/ksh-$$.log
```

Copy this in a `testfile.ksh`:

```
cat >testfile.ksh
chmod +x testfile.ksh
```

Than run it two time:

```
./testfile.ksh
. ./testfile.ksh

ls -l /tmp/ksh-*.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   2183 avr 11 13:48 /tmp/ksh-9725.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   2140 avr 11 13:48 /tmp/ksh-9781.log

echo $$
9725
```

and see:

```
diff /tmp/ksh-{9725,9781}.log | grep ^\> # OWN SUBSHELL:
> HISTCMD=0
> PPID=9725
> RANDOM=1626
> SECONDS=0.001
>   lineno=0
> SHLVL=3

diff /tmp/ksh-{9725,9781}.log | grep ^\< # SOURCED:
< COLUMNS=152
< HISTCMD=117
< LINES=47
< PPID=9163
< PS1='$ '
< RANDOM=29667
< SECONDS=23.652
<   level=1
<   lineno=1
< SHLVL=2
```

There is some variable herited in a *sourced* run, but nothing really related...

You could even check that `$SECONDS` is close to `0.000`, but that's ensure only *manualy sourced* cases...

You even could try to check for *what's* parent is:

Place this into your `testfile.ksh`:

```
ps $PPID
```

Than:

```
./testfile.ksh
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
32320 pts/4    Ss     0:00 -ksh

. ./testfile.ksh
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
32319 ?        S      0:00 sshd: user@pts/4
```

or `ps ho cmd $PPID`, but this work only for one level of subsessions...

Sorry, I couldn't find a reliable way of doing that, under [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh).

Comment: `[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ] || [ -z "$BASH_SOURCE" ]` for scripts read in via pipe (`cat script | bash`).

Comment: Note that `.` isn't an alias for `source`, it's actually the other way around. `source somescript.sh` is a Bash-ism and isn't portable, `. somescript.sh` is POSIX and portable IIRC.

Comment: This breaks your theory.  env -i echo $( source hi );                                                       contents of hi:                                                                                                                     # source me

[ "$_" == "0" ] && {
 echo "I succeed but does that really say I am sourced?"
} || {
 echo "I failed but does that mean I am not sourced?"
}

Answer (score 34):

The `BASH_SOURCE[]` answer (bash-3.0 and later) seems simplest, though `BASH_SOURCE[]` is *not documented to work outside a function body* (it currently happens to work, in disagreement with the man page).

The most robust way, as suggested by Wirawan Purwanto, is to check `FUNCNAME[1]` *within a function*:

```
function mycheck() { declare -p FUNCNAME; }
mycheck
```

Then:

```
$ bash sourcetest.sh
declare -a FUNCNAME='([0]="mycheck" [1]="main")'
$ . sourcetest.sh
declare -a FUNCNAME='([0]="mycheck" [1]="source")'
```

This is the equivalent to checking the output of `caller`, the values `main` and `source` distinguish the caller's context. Using `FUNCNAME[]` saves you capturing and parsing `caller` output. You need to know or calculate your local call depth to be correct though. Cases like a script being sourced from within another function or script will cause the array (stack) to be deeper. (`FUNCNAME` is a special bash array variable, it should have contiguous indexes corresponding to the call stack, as long as it is never `unset`.)

```
function issourced() {
    [[ ${FUNCNAME[@]: -1} == "source" ]]
}
```

(In bash-4.2 and later you can use the simpler form `${FUNCNAME[-1]}` instead for the last item in the array. Improved and simplified thanks to Dennis Williamson's comment below.)

However, your problem as stated is "*I have a script where I do not want it to call 'exit' if it's being sourced*". The common `bash` idiom for this situation is:

```
return 2>/dev/null || exit
```

If the script is being sourced then `return` will terminate the sourced script and return to the caller.

If the script is being executed, then `return` will return an error (redirected), and `exit` will terminate the script as normal. Both `return` and `exit` can take an exit code, if required.

Sadly, this doesn't work in `ksh` (at least not in the AT&T derived version I have here), it treats `return` as equivalent to `exit` if invoked outside a function or dot-sourced script.

**Updated**: What you *can* do in contemporary versions of `ksh` is to check the special variable `.sh.level` which is set to the function call depth. For an invoked script this will initially be unset, for a dot-sourced script it will be set to 1.

```
function issourced {
    [[ ${.sh.level} -eq 2 ]]
}

issourced && echo this script is sourced
```

This is not quite as robust as the bash version, you must invoke `issourced()` in the file you are testing from at the top level or at a known function depth.

(You may also be interested in [this code](https://gist.github.com/ormaaj/12874b68acd06ee98b59) on github which uses a `ksh` discipline function and some debug trap trickery to emulate the bash `FUNCNAME` array.)

The canonical answer here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/109 also offers `$-` as another indicator (though imperfect) of the shell state.

---

Notes:

- it is possible to create bash functions named "main" and "source" ([overriding the builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188327/how-do-i-explicitly-and-safely-force-the-use-of-a-built-in-command-in-bash)), these names may appear in `FUNCNAME[]` but as long as only the last item in that array is tested there is no ambiguity.
- I don't have a good answer for `pdksh`. The closest thing I can find applies only to `pdksh`, where each sourcing of a script opens a new file descriptor (starting with 10 for the original script). Almost certainly not something you want to rely on...

Comment: How about `${FUNCNAME[(( ${#FUNCNAME[@]} - 1 ))]}` to get the last (bottom) item in the stack? Then testing against "main" (negate for OP) was the most reliable for me.

Comment: If I have a `PROMPT_COMMAND` set, that shows up as the last index of the `FUNCNAME` array if I run `source sourcetest.sh`. Inverting the check (looking for `main` as the last index) seems more robust: `is_main() { [[ ${FUNCNAME[@]: -1} == "main" ]]; }`.

Comment: The man-page states, that [`FUNCNAME`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-FUNCNAME) is only available in functions.  According to my tests with `declare -p FUNCNAME`, `bash` behaves differently.  v4.3 gives an error outside functions, while v4.4 gives `declare -a FUNCNAME`.  Both(!) return `main` for `${FUNCNAME[0]}` in the main script (if it is executed) while `$FUNCNAME` gives nothing.  And:  There are so many scripts out there "ab"using `$BASH_SOURCE` outside functions, that I doubt this can or will be changed.

Comment: If all you want to do is return v. exit, use kill -1 $$ .. there are other reasons why one would want to know if they are sourced or not... I.E. subshell make environments for ({massively ,}parallel builds.  In that case, just source a new version or the environment that you ran the jobs manually.  /shrug it works... there is always a work-around, it just sucks when you're the guy always hitting the corner-case. LOL

Comment: After about a year of using and recommending the `${FUNCNAME[-1]}` technique, I have completely rescinded. It does _not_ work properly with nested scripts! You'd have to manually update the index according to the level of nesting, which isn't foreseeable nor practical. The technique using `if [ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0" ]`, however, works great with nested scripts where one script runs or sources another. So, I have [massively updated my answer and put my favorite technique at the top of it here now.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662049/4561887)

Answer (score 27):

<sup>Editor's note: This answer's solution works robustly, but is `bash`-only. It can be streamlined to

`(return 2>/dev/null)`.</sup>

**TL;DR**

Try to execute a `return` statement. If the script isn't sourced, that will raise an error. You can catch that error and proceed as you need.

Put this in a file and call it, say, test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Try to execute a `return` statement,
# but do it in a sub-shell and catch the results.
# If this script isn't sourced, that will raise an error.
$(return >/dev/null 2>&1)

# What exit code did that give?
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
    echo "This script is sourced."
else
    echo "This script is not sourced."
fi
```

Execute it directly:

```
shell-prompt> sh test.sh
output: This script is not sourced.
```

Source it:

```
shell-prompt> source test.sh
output: This script is sourced.
```

For me, this works in zsh and bash.

**Explanation**

The `return` statement will raise an error if you try to execute it outside of a function or if the script is not sourced. Try this from a shell prompt:

```
shell-prompt> return
output: ...can only `return` from a function or sourced script
```

You don't need to see that error message, so you can redirect the output to dev/null:

```
shell-prompt> return >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Now check the exit code. 0 means OK (no errors occurred), 1 means an error occurred:

```
shell-prompt> echo $?
output: 1
```

You also want to execute the `return` statement inside of a sub-shell. When the `return` statement runs it . . . well . . . returns. If you execute it in a sub-shell, it will return out of that sub-shell, rather than returning out of your script. To execute in the sub-shell, wrap it in `$(...)`:

```
shell-prompt> $(return >/dev/null 2>$1)
```

Now, you can see the exit code of the sub-shell, which should be 1, because an error was raised inside the sub-shell:

```
shell-prompt> echo $?
output: 1
```

Comment: This fails for me in 0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2

`$ readlink $(which sh)`

`dash`

`$ . test.sh` 

`This script is sourced.`

`$ ./test.sh`

`This script is sourced.`

Comment: POSIX does not specify what `return` should do at the top level (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_24_03). The `dash` shell treats a `return` at the top level as `exit`. Other shells like `bash` or `zsh` don't allow `return` at the top level, which is the feature a technique like this exploits.

Comment: It works in sh if you remove the `$` before the subshell. That is, use `(return >/dev/null 2>&1)` instead of `$(return >/dev/null 2>&1)` - but then it stops working in bash.

Comment: @Eponymous: Since `dash`, where this solution doesn't work, acts as `sh` on Ubuntu, for instance, this solution doesn't _generally_ work with `sh`. The solution does work for me in Bash 3.2.57 and 4.4.5 - with or without the `$` before `(...)` (though there's never a good reason for the `$`).

Comment: `return`ing wihout an explcit return value breaks when `source`ing the scripts just after a bad-exitted command. Proposed the enhancement edit.

Comment: Even though the `return` is written in a sourced script, the context in which it gets called is top-level and therefore it should always fail. That it does not is somewhat obviously a bug and may therefore one day be fixed, at which point this will stop working.

Answer (score 21):

FWIW, after reading all of the other answers, I came up with following solution for me:

> Update:  Actually, somebody spotted a since-corrected error in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776166/490291) which affected mine, too.  I think the update here also is an improvement (see edits if you are curious).

This works for all scripts, which **start with `#!/bin/bash`** but might be sourced by different shells as well to learn some information (like settings) which is are kept outside the `main` function.

> According to the comments below, this answer here apparently does not work for all `bash` variants.  Also not for systems, where `/bin/sh` is based on `bash`.  I. E. it fails for `bash` v3.x on MacOS.  (Currenty I do not know how to solve this.)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function definitions (API) and shell variables (constants) go here
# (This is what might be interesting for other shells, too.)

# this main() function is only meant to be meaningful for bash
main()
{
# The script's execution part goes here
}

BASH_SOURCE=".$0" # cannot be changed in bash
test ".$0" != ".$BASH_SOURCE" || main "$@"
```

Instead of the last 2 lines you can use following (in my opinion less readable) code to not set `BASH_SOURCE` in other shells and allow `set -e` to work in `main`:

```
if ( BASH_SOURCE=".$0" && exec test ".$0" != ".$BASH_SOURCE" ); then :; else main "$@"; fi
```

This script-recipe has following properties:

- If executed by `bash` the normal way, `main` is called.  Please note that this does not include a call like `bash -x script` (where `script` does not contain a path), see below.
- If sourced by `bash`, `main` is only called, if the calling script happens to have the same name.  (For example, if it sources itself or via `bash -c 'someotherscript "$@"' main-script args..` where `main-script` must be, what `test` sees as `$BASH_SOURCE`).
- If sourced/executed/read/`eval`ed by a shell other than `bash`, `main` is not called (`BASH_SOURCE` is always different to `$0`).
- `main` is not called if `bash` reads the script from stdin, unless you set `$0` to be the empty string like so: `( exec -a '' /bin/bash ) <script`
- If evaluated by `bash` with `eval`  (`` eval "`cat script`" `` *all quotes are important!*) from within some other script, this calls `main`.  If `eval` is run from commandline directly, this is similar to previous case, where the script is read from stdin. (`BASH_SOURCE` is blank, while `$0` usually is `/bin/bash` if not forced to something completely different.)
- If `main` is not called, it does return `true` (`$?=0`).
- This does not rely on unexpected behavior (previously I wrote undocumented, but I found no documentation that you cannot `unset` nor alter `BASH_SOURCE` either):

  - [`BASH_SOURCE` is a bash reserved array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-BASH_005fSOURCE).  But allowing `BASH_SOURCE=".$0"` to change it would open a very dangerous can of worms, so my expectation is, that this must have no effect (except, perhaps, some ugly warning shows up in some future version of `bash`).
  - There is no documentation that `BASH_SOURCE` works outside functions.  However the opposite (that it only works in functions) is neither documented.  The observation is, that it works (tested with `bash` v4.3 and v4.4, unfortunately I have no `bash` v3.x anymore) and that quite too many scripts would break, if `$BASH_SOURCE` stops working as observed.  Hence my expectation is, that `BASH_SOURCE` stays as is for future versions of `bash`, too.
  - In contrast (nice find, BTW!) consider `( return 0 )`, which gives `0` if sourced and `1` if not sourced.  [This comes a bit unexpected not only for me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/230654/23450) , and (according to the readings there) POSIX says, that `return` from subshell is undefined behavior (and the `return` here is clearly from a subshell).  Perhaps this feature eventually gets enough widespread use such that it can no more be changed, but AFAICS there is a much higher chance that some future `bash` version accidental changes the return behavior in that case.
- **Unfortunately `bash -x script 1 2 3` does not run `main`.** (Compare `script 1 2 3` where `script` has no path).  Following can be used as workaround:

  - `` bash -x "`which script`" 1 2 3 ``
  - `` bash -xc '. script' "`which script`" 1 2 3 ``
  - That `bash script 1 2 3` does not run `main` can be considered a feature.
- Note that `( exec -a none script )` calls `main` (`bash` does not pass it's `$0` to the script, for this you need to use `-c` as shown in the last point).

Thus, except for some some corner cases, `main` is only called, when the script is executed the usual way.  **Normally this is, what you want,** especially because it lacks complex hard to understand code.

> Note that it is very similar to the Python code:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == '__main__': main()
> ```
>
> Which also prevents calling of `main`, except for some corner cases, as
>   you can import/load the script and enforce that `__name__='__main__'`

## Why I think this is a good general way to solve the challenge

If you have something, which can be sourced by multiple shells, it must be compatible.  However (read the other answers), **as there is no (easy to implement) portable way to detect the `source`ing, you should change the rules**.

By enforcing that the script must be executed by `/bin/bash`, you exactly do this.

This **solves all cases but following** in which case the script cannot run directly:

- `/bin/bash` is not installed or disfunctional (i. E. in a boot environment)
- If you pipe it to a shell like in `curl https://example.com/script | $SHELL`
- (Note: This is only true if your `bash` is recent enough.  This recipe is reported to fail for certain variants.  So be sure to check it works for your case.)

However I cannot think about any real reason where you need that and also the ability to source the exactly same script in parallel!  Usually you can wrap it to execute the `main` by hand.  Like that:

- `$SHELL -c '. script && main'`
- `{ curl https://example.com/script && echo && echo main; } | $SHELL`
- `` $SHELL -c 'eval "`curl https://example.com/script`" && main' ``
- `` echo 'eval "`curl https://example.com/script`" && main' | $SHELL ``

## Notes

- This answer would not have been possible without the help of all the other answers!  Even the wrong ones - which initially made me posting this.
- Update: Edited due to the new discoveries found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776166/490291

Comment: Tested for ksh and bash-4.3. Nice. It's such a pity your answer will have a hard life given that the other answers already had years collecting up-votes.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I appreciated the longer, 'less readable' test with the IF statement since it's nice to handle both situations to at least give non-silent failure. In my case I need a script to be sourced or otherwise inform user of their error in not using source.

Comment: @Tino:  As for "might be sourced by different shells as well":  On macOS, where `/bin/sh` is effectively `bash` in POSIX mode, assigning to `BASH_SOURCE` _breaks_ your script.
In other shells (`dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`), invoking your script by passing it as a file argument _directly to the shell executable_ malfunctions (e.g., `zsh <your-script>` will make your script mistakenly think it is _sourced_).
(You already mention that _piping_ the code malfunctions, in all shells.)

Comment: @Tino: As an aside: While `. <your-script>` (sourcing) does work from all POSIX-like shells in principle, it only makes sense if the script was explicitly written to use POSIX features only, so as to prevent features specific to one shell from breaking execution in other shells; using a _Bash_ shebang line (rather than `#!/bin/sh`) is therefore confusing - at least without a conspicuous comment.
Conversely, if your script is meant to be run from Bash only (even if only by virtue of not considering what features may not be portable), it's better to _refuse_ execution in non-Bash shells.

Comment: @mklement0 **to your first comment:** Running bash with `export POSIXLY_CORRECT=:` I cannot spot any problem currently.  I have no macOS, though, so thanks for noting.  **And to both comments:** Actually my expectation is, that `main` is only written for `bash` and not meant for other shells (other shells need only be able to parse `main`, not to execute it correctly).  This way other shells can still `source` the script to "learn" something from it, like some shared hardcoded settings (yuck!) etc. outside of `main` (left away in the example).  It might come handy, YMMV

Comment: macOS, as of v10.14.6, uses v3.2.57 of Bash, and you can reproduce the problem there as follows: `bash --posix -c 'echo before; BASH_SOURCE=hi; echo after'` (prints just `before`); Bash v4.4.23, for instance, doesn't have that problem. As for your _both comments_ response: I encourage you to make that clear in your answer, ideally with amended code that prevents invocation of `main` from other shells or at least emits a warning first.

Comment: @mklement0 Edited, thanks for noting!  As I have no idea how to test this myself, does the 2nd variant `if ( BASH_SOURCE=".$0" && exec test ".$0" != ".$BASH_SOURCE" ); then :; else main "$@"; fi` work with macOS' bash v3.2.57?  This uses a subshell, hence *might* fail, hence *might* execute `main` as wanted under `bash`?

Comment: @Tino: The subshell always fails in v3.2.57 due to the attempt to assign to `$BASH_SOURCE`, so `main` is _always_ executed when you call from Bash / Bash acting as `sh` - whether you source the script or not.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks again, added a note that there is a problem.  **For other readers:** When sourced with bash v3.x it should not execute `main`, but it does this in this case!  And when sourced by `/bin/sh`, which is `bash --posix`, the same happens in this case, and that is plain wrong as well.

Answer (score 13):

This works later on in the script and does'nt depend on the _ variable:

```
## Check to make sure it is not sourced:
Prog=myscript.sh
if [ $(basename $0) = $Prog ]; then
   exit 1  # not sourced
fi
```

or

```
[ $(basename $0) = $Prog ] && exit
```

Comment: I think this answer is one of the few POSIX compliant here. With the obvious downsides being that you have to know the filename and it doesn't work if both scripts have the same filename.

Comment: Good simple answer even though it does require the script filename.

Comment: How about this: `is_sourced() { case $(basename "${0#-}") in sh|bash|ash|dash|ksh) return 0;; *) return 1;; esac }`

Answer (score 6):

I will give a BASH-specific answer. Korn shell, sorry. Suppose your script name is `include2.sh` ; then make a function *inside* the `include2.sh` called `am_I_sourced`. Here's my demo version of `include2.sh`:

```
am_I_sourced()
{
  if [ "${FUNCNAME[1]}" = source ]; then
    if [ "$1" = -v ]; then
      echo "I am being sourced, this filename is ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} and my caller script/shell name was $0"
    fi
    return 0
  else
    if [ "$1" = -v ]; then
      echo "I am not being sourced, my script/shell name was $0"
    fi
    return 1
  fi
}

if am_I_sourced -v; then
  echo "Do something with sourced script"
else
  echo "Do something with executed script"
fi
```

Now try to execute it in many ways:

```
~/toys/bash $ chmod a+x include2.sh

~/toys/bash $ ./include2.sh 
I am not being sourced, my script/shell name was ./include2.sh
Do something with executed script

~/toys/bash $ bash ./include2.sh 
I am not being sourced, my script/shell name was ./include2.sh
Do something with executed script

~/toys/bash $ . include2.sh
I am being sourced, this filename is include2.sh and my caller script/shell name was bash
Do something with sourced script
```

So this works without exception, and it is not using the brittle `$_` stuff. This trick uses BASH's introspection facility, i.e. built-in variables `FUNCNAME` and `BASH_SOURCE`; see their documentation in bash manual page.

Only two caveat:

1) the call to `am_I_called` *must* take place *in* the sourced script, but *not within* any function, lest `${FUNCNAME[1]}` returns something else. Yeah...you could have checked `${FUNCNAME[2]}` -- but you just make your life harder.

2) function `am_I_called` *must* reside in the sourced script if you want to find out what the name of the file being included.

Comment: Clarification: This feature requires BASH version 3+ to work. In BASH 2, FUNCNAME is a scalar variable instead of an array. Also BASH 2 does not have BASH_SOURCE array variable.

Answer (score 5):

### The most beautiful way to detect if a Bash script is being executed or sourced (imported)

I really think this is the most beautiful way to do it:

From my [`if__name__==__main___check_if_sourced_or_executed_best.sh`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/if__name__%3D%3D__main___check_if_sourced_or_executed_best.sh) file in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

main() {
    echo "Running main."
    # Add your main function code here
}

if [ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0" ]; then
    # This script is being run.
    __name__="__main__"
else
    # This script is being sourced.
    __name__="__source__"
fi

# Only run `main` if this script is being **run**, NOT sourced (imported)
if [ "$__name__" = "__main__" ]; then
    echo "This script is being run."
    main "$@"
else
    echo "This script is being sourced."
fi
```

References:

1. See also my other answer here for additional details on the above technique, including showing the run output: [What is the bash equivalent to Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662116/4561887)
2. [This answer where I first learned about `"${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29967433/4561887)

You can also explore the following alternatives if you like, but I prefer to use the code chunk above.

**Important:** Using the `"${FUNCNAME[-1]}"` technique does *not* properly handle nested scripts, where one script calls or sources another, whereas the `if [ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0" ]` technique *does*. That's another *huge* reason to use `if [ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" = "$0" ]` instead.

### 4 ways to determine whether a bash script is being *sourced* or *executed*

I have read a bunch of answers all over the place on this and a few other questions, and have come up with 4 ways I'd like to summarize and put in one place.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

See: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for what that does in Python.

1. You can see a full demonstration of all 4 techniques below in my [check_if_sourced_or_executed.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/check_if_sourced_or_executed.sh) script in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.
2. You can see one of the techniques in-use in my advanced bash program with help menu, argument parsing, `main` function, automatic *execute* vs *source* detection (akin to if `__name__ == "__main__":` in Python), etc, see my demo/template program [in this list here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world#4-bash). It is currently called [`argument_parsing__3_advanced__gen_prog_template.sh`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/argument_parsing__3_advanced__gen_prog_template.sh), but if that name changes in the future I'll update it in the list at the link just above

**Anyway, here are the 4 Bash techniques:**

1. Technique 1 (can be placed anywhere; handles nested scripts):
   See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424492/how-to-define-a-shell-script-to-be-sourced-not-run/424495#424495

   ```bash
   if [ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" -ef "$0" ]; then
       echo "  This script is being EXECUTED."
       run="true"
   else
       echo "  This script is being SOURCED."
   fi
   ```
2. Technique 2 [**My favorite technique**] (can be placed anywhere; handles nestes scripts):
   See this type of technique in-use in my most-advanced bash demo script yet, here: [argument_parsing__3_advanced__gen_prog_template.sh](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/bash/argument_parsing__3_advanced__gen_prog_template.sh), near the bottom.

   Modified from: [What is the bash equivalent to Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966449/what-is-the-bash-equivalent-to-pythons-if-name-main/29967433#29967433)

   ```bash
   if [ "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" == "$0" ]; then
       echo "  This script is being EXECUTED."
       run="true"
   else
       echo "  This script is being SOURCED."
   fi
   ```
3. Technique 3 (requires another line which MUST be **outside** all functions):
   Modified from: [How to detect if a script is being sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced/28776166#28776166)

   ```bash
   # A. Place this line OUTSIDE all functions:
   (return 0 2>/dev/null) && script_is_being_executed="false" || script_is_being_executed="true"

   # B. Place these lines anywhere
   if [ "$script_is_being_executed" == "true" ]; then
       echo "  This script is being EXECUTED."
       run="true"
   else
       echo "  This script is being SOURCED."
   fi
   ```
4. Technique 4 [Limitation: does **not** handle nested scripts!] (MUST be **inside** a function):
   Modified from: [How to detect if a script is being sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706745/4561887)
   and [Unix & Linux: How to define a shell script to be sourced not run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424552/114401).

   ```bash
   if [ "${FUNCNAME[-1]}" == "main" ]; then
       echo "  This script is being EXECUTED."
       run="true"
   elif [ "${FUNCNAME[-1]}" == "source" ]; then
       echo "  This script is being SOURCED."
   else
       echo "  ERROR: THIS TECHNIQUE IS BROKEN"
   fi
   ```

   1. This is where I first learned about the `${FUNCNAME[-1]}` trick: @mr.spuratic: [How to detect if a script is being sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706745/4561887) - he learned it from Dennis Williamson apparently.

### See also:

1. [my answer] [What is the bash equivalent to Python's `if __name__ == '__main__'`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662116/4561887)
2. [my answer] [Unix & Linux: How to define a shell script to be sourced not run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/685857/114401)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest a small correction to [Dennis' very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687092/900078), to make it slightly more portable, I hope:

```
[ "$_" != "$0" ] && echo "Script is being sourced" || echo "Script is a subshell"
```

because `[[` isn't recognized by the (somewhat anal retentive IMHO) Debian *POSIX compatible* shell, `dash`. Also, one may need the quotes to protect against filenames containing spaces, again in said shell.

Answer (score 2):

`$_` is quite brittle.  You have to check it as the first thing you do in the script.  And even then, it is not guaranteed to contain the name of your shell (if sourced) or the name of the script (if executed).

For example, if the user has set `BASH_ENV`, then at the top of a script, `$_` contains the name of the last command executed in the `BASH_ENV` script.

The best way I have found is to use `$0` like this:

```
name="myscript.sh"

main()
{
    echo "Script was executed, running main..."
}

case "$0" in *$name)
    main "$@"
    ;;
esac
```

Unfortunately, this way doesn't work out of the box in zsh due to the `functionargzero` option doing more than its name suggests, and being on by default.

To work around this, I put `unsetopt functionargzero` in my `.zshenv`.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what the OP wanted, but I often find myself needing to source a script just to load its functions (i.e. as a library). For example, for benchmarking or testing purposes.

Here's a design that works in all shells (including POSIX):

- Wrap all your top-level actions in a `run_main()` function.
- Have your sourced script check for an initial `--no-run` argument which *doesn't* perform any actions; *without* `--no-run`, it can call `run_main`.
- `source` the script using:

```
set -- --no-run "$@"
. script.sh
shift
```

The problem with `.` or `source` is that it's impossible to pass arguments to the script portably. POSIX shells ignore arguments to `.` and pass the caller's `"$@"` no matter what.

Comment: Very interesting answer. Trying to achieve that was the reason why I was looking for a solution to detect if a script was sourced. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any portable way to do this in both ksh and bash. In bash you could detect it using `caller` output, but I don't think there exists equivalent in ksh.

Comment: `$0` works in `bash`, `ksh93`, and `pdksh`.  I don't have `ksh88` to test.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [mklement0 compact expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776166/6255594).

That's neat, but I noticed that it can fail in the case of ksh when invoked as this:

```
/bin/ksh -c ./myscript.sh
```

(it thinks it's sourced and it's not because it executes a subshell)
But the expression will work to detect this:

```
/bin/ksh ./myscript.sh
```

Also, even if the expression is compact, the syntax is not compatible with all shells.

So I ended with the following code, which works for bash,zsh,dash and ksh

```
SOURCED=0
if [ -n "$ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT" ]; then 
    [[ $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT =~ :file$ ]] && SOURCED=1
elif [ -n "$KSH_VERSION" ]; then
    [[ "$(cd $(dirname -- $0) && pwd -P)/$(basename -- $0)" != "$(cd $(dirname -- ${.sh.file}) && pwd -P)/$(basename -- ${.sh.file})" ]] && SOURCED=1
elif [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    [[ $0 != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && SOURCED=1
elif grep -q dash /proc/$$/cmdline; then
    case $0 in *dash*) SOURCED=1 ;; esac
fi
```

Feel free to add exotic shells support :)

Comment: In `ksh 93+u`, `ksh ./myscript.sh` works fine for me (with my statement) - what version are you using?

Comment: I fear there is no way to _reliably_ determine if a script is being sourced using POSIX-features only: your attempt assumes Linux (`/proc/$$/cmdline`) and focuses on `dash` only (which also acts as `sh` on Ubuntu, for instance). If you're willing to make certain assumptions, you can examine `$0` for a reasonable - but incomplete - test that is portable.

Comment: ++ for the basic approach, though - I've taken the liberty to adapt it for what I think is the best portable approximation of supporting `sh` / `dash` as well, in an addendum to my answer.

Comment: Since "compatible with all shells" and "exotic shells" is mentioned, `${0##*/}` and `$()` aren't portable to at least one older Bourne shell (that I still have to use, even if it is a shame that it is necessary): `echo ${0##*/}` yields `bad substitution`, and `echo $(dirname $0)` gives `syntax error: '(' unexpected`. `echo $0` gives `-sh`.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this issue is not to write code that needs to know such a thing in order to behave correctly. And the way to do that is to put the code into a function, and not into the mainline of a script that needs to be sourced.

Code inside a function can just `return 0` or `return 1`.  This terminates just the function, so that control returns to whatever invoked the function.

This works whether the function is called from the mainline of a sourced script, from the mainline of a top-level script, or from another function.

Use sourcing to bring in "library" scripts that only define functions and perhaps variables, but don't actually execute any other top-level commands:

```
. path/to/lib.sh # defines libfunction
libfunction arg
```

or else:

```
path/to/script.sh arg # call script as a child process
```

and not:

```
. path/to/script.sh arg  # shell programming anti-pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

A small addition to the @mklement0 answer. This is the custom function I used in my script to determine whether it is sourced or not:

```
replace_shell(){
   if [ -n "$ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT" ]; then 
      case $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT in *:file*) echo "Zsh is sourced";; esac
   else
      case ${0##*/} in sh|dash|bash) echo "Bash is sourced";; esac
   fi
}
```

In a function, the output of `"$ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT"` for zsh is `toplevel:file:shfunc` and not just `toplevel:file` during sorcing; thus, `*:file*` should fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a one-liner that works on [mac, linux] with bash.version >= 3 and none of these answers fit the bill.

```sh
[[ ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} = $0 ]] && main "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Straight to the point:** you must evaluate if the variable **"$0"** is equal to the name of your Shell.

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "First Parameter: $0"
echo
if [[ "$0" == "bash" ]] ; then
    echo "The script was sourced."
else
    echo "The script WAS NOT sourced."
fi
```

**Via SHELL**:

```
$ bash check_source.sh 
First Parameter: check_source.sh

The script WAS NOT sourced.
```

**Via SOURCE**:

```
$ source check_source.sh
First Parameter: bash

The script was sourced.
```

---

It's pretty hard to have a **100% portable way** of detecting if a script was sourced or not.

Regarding my experience **(7 years with Shellscripting)**, the only safe way (not relying on environment variables with **PIDs** and so on, which is not safe due to the fact that it is something **VARIABLE**), you should:

- extend the possibilities from your if
- using switch/case, if you want to.

Both options cannot be auto scaled, but it is the safer way.

---

**For example:**

*when you source a script via an SSH session, the value returned by the variable **"$0"** (when using **source**), is **-bash**.*

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "First Parameter: $0"
echo
if [[ "$0" == "bash" || "$0" == "-bash" ]] ; then
    echo "The script was sourced."
else
    echo "The script WAS NOT sourced."
fi
```

OR

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "First Parameter: $0"
echo
if [[ "$0" == "bash" ]] ; then
    echo "The script was sourced."
elif [[ "$0" == "-bash" ]] ; then
    echo "The script was sourced via SSH session."
else
    echo "The script WAS NOT sourced."
fi
```

Comment: Downvoted, as this is plain wrong:  `/bin/bash -c '. ./check_source.sh'` gives `The script WAS NOT sourced.`.  Same bug: `ln -s /bin/bash pumuckl; ./pumuckl -c '. ./check_source.sh'` -> `The script WAS NOT sourced.`

Comment: Your downvote has changed the whole scenario and made a great contribution, Tino. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with checking `[[ $_ == "$(type -p "$0")" ]]`

```
if [[ $_ == "$(type -p "$0")" ]]; then
    echo I am invoked from a sub shell
else
    echo I am invoked from a source command
fi
```

When use `curl ... | bash -s -- ARGS` to run remote script on-the-fly, the $0 will be just `bash` instead of normal `/bin/bash` when run actual script file, so I use `type -p "$0"` to show full path of bash.

test:

```
curl -sSL https://github.com/jjqq2013/bash-scripts/raw/master/common/relpath | bash -s -- /a/b/c/d/e /a/b/CC/DD/EE

source <(curl -sSL https://github.com/jjqq2013/bash-scripts/raw/master/common/relpath)
relpath /a/b/c/d/e /a/b/CC/DD/EE

wget https://github.com/jjqq2013/bash-scripts/raw/master/common/relpath
chmod +x relpath
./relpath /a/b/c/d/e /a/b/CC/DD/EE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a spin off from some other answers, regarding "universal" cross shell support.  This is admittedly very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942183/3220983 in particular, though slightly different.  The weakness with this, is that a client script must respect how to use it (i.e. by exporting a variable first).  The strength is that this is simple and should work "anywhere". Here's a template for your cut & paste pleasure:

```
# NOTE: This script may be used as a standalone executable, or callable library.
# To source this script, add the following *prior* to including it:
# export ENTRY_POINT="$0"

main()
{
    echo "Running in direct executable context!"
}

if [ -z "${ENTRY_POINT}" ]; then main "$@"; fi
```

*Note: I use `export` just be sure this mechanism can be extended into sub processes.*

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution (depends on readlink from GNU coreutils):

```bash
if [ "$(readlink -f "$(command -v "$0")")" != "$(readlink -f /proc/$$/exe)" ]; then
  echo "Is executed"
fi
```

This compares:

1. The current command name (if executed: script name, if sourced: the shell interpreter)
2. The current executable (always the shell interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

This should be sh compliant, specifically compliant with busybox ash (which doesn't have the above handy bash-esque one-liners).

This has the same idea as [jim mcnamara's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942183/6069586) solution above, but instead of hardcoding the filename as a variable, you fetch it, and compare basenames.
The code comes from [how to get a sourced filename in busybox ash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71084642/get-sourced-filename-in-busybox-ash).

```sh
THIS_FILE="$(lsof | grep '^'$$ | tail -n1 | awk '{print $3}')"
[ "${0##*/}" != "${THIS_FILE##*/}" ] && sourced='yes' || sourced='no'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for bash, zsh, ksh & dash.

I did see an issue with sourcing detection when sourcing from a file executed by dash.

```bash
executingName="${0##*/}"
separator='+'
SHS="${separator?}sh${separator?}dash${separator?}-sh${separator?}-dash${separator?}"
sourced="${BASH_VERSION:+$( 
  ( 2>/dev/null return 0 ) || test 0 -eq ${??} ;
)${??
}}${ZSH_VERSION:+$(
  test "${ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT##*:file}" != "${ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT-}" ;
)${??
}}${KSH_VERSION:+$(
  test "${executingName?
    }" = "${0-}" -o "${executingName?
    }" != "${.sh.file##*/}"
)${??}}$(
  test "${SHS#*${separator?}${executingName?
    }${separator?}}" != "${SHS?
    }" && printf '%s' "${??}"
)"
printf '%9s' "$(
  test 0 -ne ${sourced:-8} && printf "unsourced" || printf "sourced"
)"
```

Mostly based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776166/165330  w/ "cheatsheet" for info about parameter expansion https://steinbaugh.com/posts/posix.html , and changing the case-esac into a substitution i saw over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43912605 .

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted a couple of very good answers and ended up with these 2 lines for bash:

```
function do_not_source { [[ "${FUNCNAME[-1]}" != "source" ]]; }
do_not_source || return 2
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use a shebang line and check if it is being Executed instead.**

Your script should have a shebang line `#!/path/to/shell` saying what shell it should run in. Otherwise, you will have other cross shell compatibility issues as well.

Therefore, you only need to check if its being executed by attempting a command that does not work when being sourced.

eg. For a Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if (return 0 2>/dev/null); then
    echo "Script was sourced."
fi
```

This method also works for zsh and sh just change the shebang line.