# Determining whether shell script was executed "sourcing" it

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible for a shell script to test whether it was executed through `source`? That is, for example,

```
$ source myscript.sh
$ ./myscript.sh
```

Can *myscript.sh* distinguish from these different shell environments?

Comment: That's running two _different_ scripts by the way, `myscript.sh` and `myscript` - Fixing...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if a script is being sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think, what Sam wants to do may be not possible.

To what degree a half-baken workaround is possible, depends on...

- ...the default shell of users, and
- ...which alternative shells they are allowed to use.

If I understand Sam's requirement correctly, he wants to have a 'script',
`myscript`, that is...

1. ...not *directly* executable via invoking it by its name `myscript`
   (i.e. that has `chmod a-x`);
2. ...not *indirectly* executable for users by invoking `sh myscript` or
   invoking `bash myscript`
3. ...***only*** running its contained functions and commands if invoked by
   sourcing it: `. myscript`

The first things to consider are these

1. Invoking a script directly by its name (`myscript`) requires a first line in
   the script like `#!/bin/bash` or similar. This will directly determine which
   installed instance of the bash executable (or symlink) will be invoked to run
   the script's content. This will be a new shell process. It requires the
   scriptfile itself to have the executable flag set.
2. Running a script by invoking a shell binary with the script's (path+)name as
   an argument (`sh myscript`), is the same as '1.' -- ***except that the
   executable flag does not need to be set, and said first line with the
   hashbang isn't required either***. The only thing needed is that the invoking
   user needs *read* access to the scriptfile.
3. Invoking a script by sourcing its filename (`. myscript`) is very much the
   same as '1.' -- ***exept that it isn't a new shell that is invoked. All the
   script's commands are executed in the current shell***, using its environment
   (and also "polluting" its environment with any (new) variables it may set or
   change. (Usually this is a very dangerous thing to do: but here it could be
   used to execute `exit $RETURNVALUE` under certain conditions....)

**For '1.':**
Easy to achieve: `chmod a-x myscript` will prevent `myscript` from being
directly executable. But this will not fullfill requirements '2.' and '3.'.

**For '2.' and '3.':**
Much harder to achieve. Invokations by `sh myscript` require *reading*
privileges for the file. So an obvious way out would seem to `chmod a-r
myscript`. However, this will also dis-allow '3.': you will not be able to
source the script either.

So what about writting the script in a way that uses a *Bashism*? A Bashism is a
specific way to do something which other shells do not understand: using
specific variables, commands etc. This could be used inside the script to
discover this condition and "do something" about it (like "display warning.txt",
"mailto admin" etc.). But there is no way in hell that this will prevent `sh` or
`bash` or any other shell from reading and trying to execute all the following
commands/lines written into the script unless you kill the shell by invoking
`exit`.

*Examples:* in Bash, the environment seen by the script knows of `$BASH`,
`$BASH_ARGV`, `$BASH_COMMAND`, `$BASH_SUBSHELL`, `BASH_EXECUTION_STRING`... . If
invoked by `sh` (also if *sourced* inside a `sh`), the executing shell will see
all these `$BASH_*` as empty environment variables. Again, this could be used
inside the script to discover this condition and "do something"... *but not
prevent the following commands from being invoked!*

I'm now assuming that...

1. ...the script is using `#!/bin/bash` as its first line,
2. ...users have set Bash as their shell and are invoking commands in the
   following table from Bash and it is their *login shell*,
3. ...`sh` is available and it is a symlink to `bash` or `dash`.

This will mean the following invokations are possible, with the listed values
for environment variables

```
vars+invok's   | ./scriptname | sh scriptname | bash scriptname | . scriptname
---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------
$0             | ./scriptname | ./scriptname  | ./scriptname    | -bash
$SHLVL         | 2            | 1             | 2               | 1
$SHELLOPTS     | braceexpand: | (empty)       | braceexpand:..  | braceexpand:
$BASH          | /bin/bash    | (empty)       | /bin/bash       | /bin/bash
$BASH_ARGV     | (empty)      | (empty)       | (empty)         | scriptname
$BASH_SUBSHELL | 0            | (empty)       | 0               | 0
$SHELL         | /bin/bash    | /bin/bash     | /bin/bash       | /bin/bash
$OPTARG        | (empty)      | (empty)       | (emtpy)         | (emtpy)
```

Now you could put a logic into your text script:

- If `$0` is not equal to `-bash`, then do an `exit $SOMERETURNVALUE`.

In case the script was called via `sh myscript` or `bash myscript`, then it will
exit the calling shell. In case it was run in the current shell, it will
continue to run. (Warning: in case the script has any other `exit` statements,
your current shell will be 'killed'...)

So put into your non-executable `myscript.txt` near its beginning something like
this may do something close to your goal:

```
echo BASH=$BASH
test x${BASH} = x/bin/bash && echo "$? :    FINE.... You're using 'bash ...'"
test x${BASH} = x/bin/bash || echo "$? :    RATS !!! -- You're not using BASH and I will kick you out!"
test x${BASH} = x/bin/bash || exit 42
test x"${0}" = x"-bash"    && echo "$? :    FINE.... You've sourced me, and I'm your login shell."
test x"${0}" = x"-bash"    || echo "$? :    RATS !!! -- You've not sourced me (or I'm not your bash login shell) and I will kick you out!"
test x"${0}" = x"-bash"    || exit 33
```

Comment: Thanks for you thorough analysis

Comment: Awesome answer. I wish I could give you more than just one upvote.

Comment: @David Wolever: You are free to find other awesome answers of mine and upvote them. :-)   (Only if you are interested in tags like PDF, Ghostscript, PostScript...)

Answer (score 15):

This may or may not be what the asker wanted but, on a similar situation, I wanted a script to indicate that it is meant to be sourced and not directly run.

To achieve this effect my script reads:

```
#!/bin/echo Should be run as: source
export SOMEPATH="/some/path/on/my/system"
echo "Your environment has been set up"
```

So when I run it either as a command or sourced I get:

```
$ ./myscript.sh
Should be run as: source ./myscript.sh

$ source ./myscript.sh
Your environment has been set up
```

You can of course fool the script by running it as `sh ./myscript.sh`, but at least it gives the correct expected behaviour on 2 out of 3 cases.

Comment: Great idea, event if not perfect.

Comment: Way to hack a difficult problem! Worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I was looking for:

```sh
[[ ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} = $0 ]] && main "$@"
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot add comment yet (stackexchange policies) so I add my own answer:

This one may works regardless if we do:

- `bash scriptname`
- `scriptname`
- `./scriptname`.

on both `bash` and `mksh`.

```
if [ "${0##/*}" == scriptname ]  # if the current name is our script
then
    echo run
else
    echo sourced
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a non-altering file path for regular users, then:

```
if [ "$(/bin/readlink -f "$0")" = "$KNOWN_PATH_OF_THIS_FILE" ]; then
    # the file was executed
else
    # the file was sourced
fi
```

(it can also easily be loosened to only check for the filename or whatever).

But your users need to have read permission to be able to source the file, so absolutely *nothing* can stop them from doing what they want with the file. But it might help them out to not use it in the wrong way.

This solution is not dependent on Bashisms.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Kurt Pfeifle’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3708439), this works for me

```sh
if [ $SHLVL = 1 ]
then
  echo 'script was sourced'      
fi
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/1d9237a/bootstrap.sh#L7)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. In general you can do the following:

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                       

sourced () {
    echo Sourced
}

executed () {
    echo Executed
}

if [[ ${0##*/} == -* ]]; then
    sourced
else
    executed $@
fi
```

Giving the following output:

```
$ ./myscript
Executed
$ . ./myscript
Sourced
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all of our machines have history, I did this:

```
check_script_call=$(history |tail -1|grep myscript.sh )
if [ -z "$check_script_call" ];then
    echo "This file should be called as a source."
    echo "Please, try again this way:"
    echo "$ source /path/to/myscript.sh"
    exit 1
fi
```

Everytime you run a script (without source), your shell creates a new env without history.

If you want to care about performance you can try this:

```
if ! history |tail -1|grep set_vars ;then
    echo -e "This file should be called as a source.\n"
    echo "Please, try again this way:"
    echo -e "$ source /path/to/set_vars\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

PS: I think Kurt's answer is much more complete but I think this could help.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `$0` will be "myscript.sh".  In the second case, it will be "./myscript".  But, in general, there's no way to tell `source` was used.

If you tell us what you're trying to do, instead of how you want to do it, a better answer might be forthcoming.

Comment: How to force a shell script being executed through sourcing only?

Comment: @Sam: don't mark it executable?  But **why** do you want to do this?  What is it you're actually trying to **do**?

Comment: @Borealid: I did considered `chmod -x`, but this didn't prevent people from using $ sh myscript.sh

Comment: @Borealid: the script is primarily for setting environment vars

Comment: @Borealid: What you say is plain wrong. If you run `. ./myscript.sh` from a Bash login shell, your `"$0"` will be `"-bash"`.

Comment: @Sam: And it is not feasible to put these environment variables into user's  `~/.profile` ?

Comment: @pipitas: You've got an extra dot there.  Try using the `source` command.

Comment: @Borealid: Which dot do you mean? `~/.profile` is fine. It needs a dot as part of the filename. -- `. ./myscript.sh` is also fine. The first dot here is a shortcut for invoking the `source` command. The second dot means *in the current directory*.