# How do I get the script name being executed in bash?

Tags: shell, bash

So I am trying to make a portable bashrc/bash_profile file. I have a single script that I am symbolically linking to .bashrc, .bash_profile, etc. I am then looking at `$0` and switching what I do based on which script was called. The problem is what the shell calls the bashrc script of course it executes bash really which means `$0` for me is `-bash`. `$1` further more is not set to the script name.

So my question is, in bash how can I get the name of the script being executed. Not the binary executing it, e.g. bash?

I assume its giving me `-bash` with `$1` not being set because it is really not a new process. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192319/how-do-i-know-the-script-file-name-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `BASH_ARGV` should work, it appears the script is [**being sourced**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3664225/determining-whether-shell-script-was)

```
$BASH_ARGV
```

Comment: Means this is not generic. When parsing $ARGV you'll have to know about that you have been called by an other script. Maybe I'm wrong. If I'm wrong you should enhance explanation of your answer, e.g. add an example

Answer (score 32):

Try:

`readlink -f ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`

or just:

`${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`.

*Remarks*:

`$0` only works when user executes "./script.sh"

`$BASH_ARGV` only works when user executes ". script.sh" or "source script.sh"

`${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` works on both cases.

`readlink -f` is useful when symbolic link is used.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it gives more detail and explains the different scenarios clearer.

Answer (score 0):

create .sh file lets say view.sh then put

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "The script is being executed..."
readlink -f ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
```