# bash multiple expressions in an if statement with "$@"

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I want to make an exclusive or in bash. When I define variables `a` and `b`, I can use this:

```
> a=1
> b=
> [ -z "$b" -a "$a" -o "$b" -a -z "$a" ] && echo yes
yes
```

However, when I try the same construction with the shell variables I'm actually interested in, it fails:

```
> [ -z "$BASH_ARGV" -a "$@" -o "$BASH_ARGV" -a -z "$@" ] && echo sourced
bash: [: argument expected
```

What's going on?

Comment: If you just want to see if the number of arguments is nonzero, just look at `$#`. No need to look at `$@`'s actual value if the number of entries it contains is all you care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"$@"` expands to one "word" per script argument, which means that it will expand to nothing if there are no script arguments. On the other hand, `"$BASH_ARGV"` expands to the first value in the array `$BASH_ARGV` if that array exists and otherwise empty. So I'm not sure what you actually want to compare.

But the main point is that `"$@"` expands to zero or more words. If it doesn't expand to a single word, then your expression is going to be syntactically incorrect. (Probably. It's possible that the entire set of arguments happens to be a valid expression.)

If you wanted to concatenate all the arguments together, you should use `"$*"`. But that's still not comparable to `"$BASH_ARGV"`. It's not really comparable to `"${BASH_ARGV[*]}"` either, but the latter would be somewhat more similar.

You might want to check out `BASH_ARGC`, too.

Comment: I only care if `BASH_ARGV` is empty or not. [I'm trying to determine if a script is run with `source` or in it's own shell.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664225/determining-whether-shell-script-was-executed-sourcing-it) It's not a robust test (depends on how the current shell was launched), but it's just for me to use, and works in the situations I want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

`"$@"` expands to individual words. You want either `"$*"` or `$# -gt 0`

<strike>With that "or" in the middle, you probably want:</strike>

```
[ -z "$BASH_ARGV" -a "$*" ] || [ "$BASH_ARGV" -a -z "$*" ]
```

Or, use the bash-specific

```
[[ (-z "$BASH_ARGV" -a "$*") || ("$BASH_ARGV" -a -z "$*") ]]
```

Nevermind: `-a` has higher priority than `-o`

Comment: I usually just use `$1`. Yes, technically it could be the empty string, but that's extremely unlikely to happen by accident.