# bash script with variables not getting set

Tags: bash, shell

I have a seemingly simple bash script to setup my environment:
The first two lines are:

```
#!/bin/bash
export CVE_ENV_DIR=$PWD
```

easy, hey? Well, see what happens when I run it, I get the following output:

```
$ echo $PWD
/work/env
$ ./env.sh 
$ echo $CVE_ENV_DIR

$
```

Why does CVE_ENV_DIR not get set to `/work/env`? What is happening here? When I type `export CVE_ENV_DIR=$PWD` manually on the shell, it works as expected...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Child shells cannot affect the environment of their parent. If you want the script to affect the parent's environment, you need to:

```
source ./env.sh
```

So what's going on? When you run a bash script, either by `bash env.sh` or `env.sh`, you're spawning a program with its own environment, an environment that's divorced from its parent. But, when you run the commands contained in the script at the command line, or using `source`, there is no spawned environment.

---

Edit to address @syme's comment. Bash scripts meant to be read using `source` are often pure configuration, containing only assignments and calculations. It's possible to also make them a little more helpful and self-documenting with a [clever she-bang hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24611678/2908724) like:

```
#!/bin/echo USAGE: source 
# Default configuration file for the Frobnicator package.

FOO=bar
BAR=$(stat /baz)
[[ -f /baz ]] && BAZ=file || BAZ=

export FOO BAR BAZ
```

Making a bash script meant for configuration *look* like a configuration script, you help future maintainers. You also help yourself my modularizing your script code into distinct parts, each part with its one unique function.

As a side note, please don't [export on the same line as you assign](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/438236/50240).

Comment: And I would have added two little things. Since the script is no longer executed: the execution rights are no longer necessary (only those of reading), and the shebang either.