# How to implicitly run a shell script sourced?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, scripting

I have made a shell script to run as terminal command, but the `cd` commands inside it is not effective and hence I want to run it with `source` so that the `cd` commands take effect.

script name : `"project.sh"`

I added this file to `/usr/local/bin`, made it executable by `chmod +x project.sh` and it runs fine, but the `cd` command is not working.

I know it runs in a child process and hence at the end terminal returns back to the starting directory, rendering no effect of `cd` commands inside `project.sh`.

The solutions presented at [Sol:1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50208/how-to-change-the-working-directory-of-invoking-shell-using-a-script) do not work for me, because they asks me to run `source <file>`, which is not possible if I want to use it as Bash command.

Comment: Just define a *function* (for example in your `.bashrc`).

Comment: If what you ask for were possible, it would be a nightmare (as an end-user): Right now, I can be assured that any command I run that isn't a shell builtin, function or alias will leave my shell's state (working directory, variables, etc) alone. You're asking for a way to violate that promise: It can't, **and shouldn't**, be done. Thus: It's impossible, and it's **intentionally** impossible, for good reasons.

Comment: ...there are commands that automatically edit a user's dotfiles, such as rvm, but it's a lot of work to do that in a way that's well-behaved (makes backups, etc) and adequately documented (so the user understands they need to restart open shells or re-source their dotfiles from them, etc).

Answer (score 4):

You use the `source` command:

```
source /usr/local/bin/project.sh
```

There's no way to make this happen automatically by typing the script name, that always runs the script in a subprocess. If you don't want to have to type this all out, you could create an alias in your `.bashrc` to simplify it:

```
alias project='source /usr/local/bin/project.sh'
```

Then typing `project` will be translated to that full command.

Comment: [Barmar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) alias is a way but is there any way were i dont have to do that process ? Is it possible to set the script as source by default ? or some way i can add it to script so that script runs as sourced ? I want to make it like a package so that others can simply run it and all those parameters are set from the script itself.

Comment: You see where I said there's no way to make it happen automatically? I meant it.

Comment: @ronpatel: The cumbersome-yet-only-feasible solution is to write an _installation mechanism_ that adds the sourcing command (whether via an alias or a function) to the user's shell profile / initialization file, complemented by logic in the script that makes it refuse to run when invoked _without_ sourcing; my (updated) answer has more.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, `source <file>` *is* a Bash command - it uses the `source` *builtin* to run script `<file>` in the context of the *current* shell rather than in a child process, thus allowing commands in `<file>` to change the current shell's environment, such as in terms of the working directory (using `cd`).
Using `source`, or its alias `.`, is (ultimately) the *only* way to achieve that.

If your intent is **not to have to invoke `<script>` *explicitly* with `source`**, you have two options, both of which are **best defined in your Bash profile, `~/.bash_profile`** (since you're on OS X; on Linux, use `~/.bashrc`<sup>[1]</sup>):

I'll assume that your script is `/path/to/foo`, and that you want to invoke it *sourced* as just `foo`:

- Option 1: Define an **alias**: `alias foo='source "/path/to/foo"'`
- Option 2: Define a **function**: `foo() { source "/path/to/foo"; }`

Both aliases and functions execute in the *current* shell, allowing you to effectively *hide* the `source` call behind a single command; aliases are generally a little easier to define, but functions offer more flexibility.

By virtue of the alias / function being defined in your Bash profile, which itself is *implicitly sourced*, the commands in `/path/to/foo` will affect your interactive shells' environment.

**Note**: Either definition of `foo` will only be available in *interactive* shells (those that (automatically) source `~/.bash_profile`). 
Additional steps would be needed to make `foo` work inside non-sourced scripts as well, but at that point you should ask yourself whether you're *obscuring* things by not making the fact that `/path/to/foo` is getting *sourced* explicit.

---

If you're **writing a script that must be sourced for *distribution to others***:

- Install the sourcing command in the user's shell profile / initialization file (as described above) *on installation* of your script.

  - If there is no installation process (and also to enable on-demand installation in general), implement a command-line option for your script such as `i` (`--install`) that performs this installation on demand.
    Preferably, also implement an *uninstallation* option.
- Either way, build logic into the script so that it refuses to run when run *without* sourcing, and have the error message contain instructions on how to install sourcing.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776166/45375) for how to detect sourcing.

<sup>A real-world implementation of the above - although more elaborate due to being *multi*-shell - is my [typex utility](https://github.com/mklement0/typex); source code [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/typex/stable/bin/typex).</sup>

---

<sup>[1] On *OS X*, Bash instances started by Terminal.app are *login* shells, which means that the only (user-specific) file that is *automatically* sourced on startup is `~/.bash_profile`.

By contrast, on most *Linux* systems Bash instances are *non*-login shells, where only `~/.bashrc` is automatically sourced.

While it is common practice to source `~/.bashrc` from one's `~/.bash_profile`, this has to be configured manually and therefore cannot be relied upon blindly.</sup>