# bash: exit from sourced script

Tags: bash

My bash script uses a lot of checks like:

```
if [ something bad ] ; then
    echo "error message"
    exit 1
fi
```

I have found out that if the user executes it via `source my-script.sh` rather than `./my-script.sh`, this `exit 1` **closes the user's shell !**
And the user sees no error message !

How do I know that the script is sourced, and how do I exit (with non-zero status code) the sourced script? In general, what can I do about this?

Comment: It's OK to document whether your script should be sourced or executed, and expect the user to follow that requirement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems there could be 2 parts to this.  The first is to know when you're executing in a `source`d script instead of an executed one.  That can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776166/4687135) answer, and for bash they suggest:

```
[[ "$0" != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && sourced=1 || sourced=0
```

to tell whether or not you are being sourced.

If you are being sourced, you'd want to use `return` instead of `exit`.

You could store that function in a variable with something like

```
if [[ $sourced -eq 1 ]]; then
    ret=return
else
    ret=exit
fi
```

and then when you want to use the appropriate one you'd just use

```
$ret 1
```

Answer (score 7):

Define:

`[[ "$0" == "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && ret=exit || ret=return`

Use:

`$ret 1`

Answer (score 4):

For those who prefer `if`:

```
# find out how the script was invoked
# we don't want to end the user's terminal session!
if [[ "$0" != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] ; then
  # this script is executed via `source`!
  # An `exit` will close the user's console!
  EXIT=return
else
  # this script is not `source`-d, it's safe to exit via `exit`
  EXIT=exit
fi
```

and then

```
$EXIT 1
```

Comment: Don't use uppercase for your script's private variables. All caps is reserved for system variables.