# How to activate python env via linux script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, virtualenv, centos7

**System:**

- Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) / CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
- Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64
- Server from Provider - i am just a user

---

Hello this is my Path to my virtual env activate, which is currently running a django app.

`/home/username/.local/env_myapp/bin/activate`

if run the command

`$ source /home/username/.local/env_myapp/bin/activate`

The env`$ (my_env)` starts in the terminal.

I wanted to write a little script to automate the env starting without putting the whole path every time in the console.

so i looked into the `activate` file...

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly
```

---

alright so u wrote this few lines in my script.

### my_env

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash
source /home/username/.local/env_myapp/bin/activate
echo "check - activate env"
exit
```

- if i run `$ my_env` it only echos "check - activate"
- if i run `$ source my_env` it runs to echo "check - activate" and then my terminal in VScode vanishes.

---

### Question

---

So how to activate python env via linux script correctly?

---

Dear Stackoverflow, this Question was about how to start the env via script and not about `exit` - as you flag this as a duplicate. Furthermore ny question is solved with the comments under my question, but i can not "solve" it. So wrote an answer down below - see "update" and credits to answers.

Comment: Remove the `exit` from the script if you don't want it to make the invoking shell exit itself when `source`d. There's **never** a reason to make `exit` or `exit "$?"` the last line of a script -- that's what it _always_ does when it reaches the end no matter what!

Comment: This is arguably a duplicate of [exit from source'd script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857332/bash-exit-from-source-d-script), or [terminal closes when I start script with dot at the start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596107) (keeping in mind that `.` is a synonym for `source`).

Comment: Also remove the `#!` line from the top - there is no useful purpose in executing (as opposed to sourcing) such a script, because doing so cannot affect any variables in the parent shell, and any `#!` line is only relevant to executing a script. The purpose of sourcing the activate script is to set relevant environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

thanks to @Charles Duffy @alaniwi

```
source /home/username/.local/env_myapp/bin/activate
echo "check - activate env"
```

now the Script starts my env in the terminal.

(did know how to close the Question, via Question comments. so i wrote the answers of @Charles Duffy @alaniwi here)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a shell function that automatically activates the environment when you `cd` into the directory. (This assumes that your pyenv is in the Python project directory, not e.g., in your `$HOME/pyenv` or such.)

```sh
# Automatically en/dis-able Python virtual environments:
function cd() {
    builtin cd "$@"
    set_python_env
}

function set_python_env() {
    env=".pyenv"
    if [[ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]]
    then
        # If env folder is found then activate the virtual env. This only
        # works when cd'ing into the top level Python project directory, not
        # straight into a sub directory. This is probably the common use
        # case as Python depends on the directory hierarchy.
        if [[ -d "$env" ]]
        then
            VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
            source "$env/bin/activate"
        fi
    else
        # Check the current folder belong to the current VIRTUAL_ENV. If
        # yes then do nothing, else deactivate, and possibly re-activate if
        # we switched to another venv.
        parentdir="$(dirname "$VIRTUAL_ENV")"
        if [[ "$PWD"/ != "$parentdir"/* ]]
        then
            deactivate
            set_python_env
        fi
    fi
}

# Activate an environment immediately; that way it's activated when you
# open the Terminal and it starts you in the Python project directory.
set_python_env
```

Either copy the above into your `~/.bashrc` or `source` it from there.

Answer (score -1):

> So how to activate python env via linux script correctly?

Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (almost every Linux program except `/sbin/init` is started with  `execve`).

So you *might* start your python script with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), so `#!/usr/bin/python` (and make it executable with [chmod(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html)).

Be aware of your [`$PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (see [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and [exec(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)).

Your [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) is probably [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (see also [getpwent(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwent.3.html) and [passwd(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html)), so read its documentation (I personally prefer [zsh](https://zsh.org/)) or at least [bash(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)