# sh return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, operating-system

**return statement error:urn: can only `return' from a function or sourced script in shell script**
myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Incorrect Usage : Arguments mismatch."
    return 2
fi

mv $1 $2

return 0
```

When i try to run

sh myscript.sh

```
Incorrect Usage : Arguments mismatch.
myscript.sh.sh: line 5: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

how to fix that error ?

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. If you want to know if your script is being *sourced* or *executed*, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2683279/7552) has some answers for you.

Answer (score 45):

I guess you mean

```
exit 2
```

and

```
exit 0
```

Also, have a second look at the syntax of [test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test).

Comment: this script not working on opensuse linux.works on ubuntu.There is any diffrence between ubuntu bash and opensuse bash?

Comment: i want to use return statement.

Comment: The error message is indicating you can't use a "return" statement as you want. Change your code to write a function (you can use return inside a function), and then check for the returned value (#?).

Comment: Please clarify your question and state what exactly it is you are trying to do with that script. As your shell is telling you, you cannot `return` from a shell script. Exit sets the exit code and returns from the script. Alternatively use @aicastell's suggestion and wrap it in a function to be able to use `return`.

Comment: Why do you want to use the `return` statement, what do you expect it to do?  When you say "not working", please describe exactly what happens.

Comment: in SUSE terminal.return statement does not work.i dont know why?i want to know why the return statement not working in suse linux.

Comment: when i try to run sh myscript.sh it gives error like sh can only returns sourced script ...how can i fix it?

Comment: Like @glenn jackman commented on your question, you might have fallen for the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).