# sh - check to see if script is being sourced

Tags: sh

I am currently writing some scripts to be utilized in an alpine linux container, and I want this be as lightweight as possible so I am refraining from installing `bash`.  I plan on sourcing a shell script, but don't want it to execute when I `source` it.

I understand that if I was using `bash` I could easily do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

main(){
    echo "something witty"
}

if [[ "$_" -eq "$0" ]]; then
    main
fi
```

But I am drawing a blank for `sh`.

Here is a demo of the lack of ability to us `$_` in `sh` for an attempt at simular functionality:

```
/ # ./test.sh
+ echo 

/ # cat test.sh 
#!/bin/sh

set -ex

echo "$_"
/ # echo "$_"
test.sh
/ #
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Honestly, I'd look at why you are sourcing it in the first place if you don't want it to actually do anything, rather than making it detect if it was sourced.

Comment: @chepner that is a good point.  I was really only sourcing a script to use an 8 line function again.  I have since just copied the function to my second script, but I am more curious than anything else now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if a script is being sourced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced)