# bash function - determine if running as a script or tty

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Say I have a bash function:

```
run_stuff(){
   if is_in_script; then
      exit 1
   fi
   return 1;
}
```

basically, if I am running it in a script:

```
$ ./my-script.sh
```

then I want to exit with 1, but if I am running it directly in the terminal:

```
$ run_stuff
```

then I want to return 1 (o/w my terminal window will close)

what is the best way to check this cross-platform?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$0`.

`echo $0` when run in my (bash) terminal returns `-bash`.

`echo $0` in a script with no `#!` run with `bash test.sh` returns `test.sh`

`echo $0` in a script with `#!/bin/bash` run as `./test.sh` returns `./test.sh`

Answer (score 0):

It's not bullet proof, but you can check whether the current shell is interactive:

```
is_in_script() {
  [[ $- == *i* ]]
}
```

However, I would just make `run_stuff` always `return`, and if a script should exit when the command reports failure, it can do `run_stuff || exit` rather than leaving this behavior up to the function itself.