# Using a variable as a case pattern in Bash

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a Bash script that uses a variable as a pattern in a *case* statement. However, I just cannot get it to work.

Case statement:

```
case "$1" in
    $test)
        echo "matched"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "didn't match"
        ;;
esac
```

I've tried this with assigning `$test` as `aaa|bbb|ccc`, `(aaa|bbb|ccc)`, `[aaa,bbb,ccc]` and several other combinations. I also tried these as the pattern in the case statement: `@($test)`, `@($(echo $test))`, `$($test)`. Also no success.

For clarity, I would like the variable to represent multiple patterns like this:

```
case "$1" in
    aaa|bbb|ccc)
        echo "matched"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "didn't match"
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `extglob` option:

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s extglob         # enables pattern lists like @(...|...)
test='@(aaa|bbb|ccc)'

for x in aaa bbb ccc ddd ; do
    echo -n "$x "
    case "$x" in
        $test) echo Matches.
        ;;
        *) echo Does not match.
    esac
done
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me the use of `extglob`. By the way `test='@(aaa|bbb|ccc)'`also works and is probably better option in this case.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks! @anubhava Why would your suggestion be better (@ instead of +)?

Comment: @anubhava Never mind, found it [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching). @ matches one occurrence, + matches multiple.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something a bit different:

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern1="aaa bbb ccc"
pattern2="hello world"
test=$(echo -e "$pattern1\n$pattern2" | grep -e $1)

case "$test" in
    "$pattern1")
        echo "matched - pattern1"
        ;;
    "$pattern2")
        echo "matched - pattern2"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "didn't match"
        ;;
esac
```

This makes use of `grep` to do the pattern matching for you, but still allows you to specify multiple pattern sets to be used in a case-statement structure.

For instance:

- If either `aaa`, `bbb`, or `ccc` is the first argument to the script, this will output `matched - pattern1`.
- If either `hello` or `world` is the first argument, this will output `matched - pattern2`.
- Otherwise it will output `didn't match`.

Comment: @Guru is right. This only matches the first since `test` becomes `aaa`.

Answer (score 2):

Using *[eval](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)* also works:

```
eval 'case "$1" in

    '$test')
        echo "matched"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "did not match"
        ;;
esac'
```

Comment: But *eval* is evil(?).

Comment: *["The command `eval` is a very risky command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874389/test-for-a-bash-variable-being-unset-using-a-function#comment48595199_6006055)*